# Am I using contain wrong?

Tags: c#, string, contains

Something weird is happening to me. I have to following function:

```
private string CategoryByName(string path) {
        path.ToLower();
        if (path.Contains("obs") || path.Contains("obst")||path.Contains("birthing")) return "Birthing";
        if (path.Contains("sbu2")||(!path.Contains("sbu3")&&path.Contains("gyn"))) return "Gynecology SBU2";
        if (path.Contains("sbu3")) return "Gynecology SBU3";
        if (path.Contains("dia") || path.Contains("sprint")||(path.Contains("strechers"))) return "Strechers";
        if (path.Contains("one_day") || path.Contains("one day") || (path.Contains("oda"))) return "One-day care";
        return "";            
    }
```

I go through a list of file names. Including ex. "INDO OBST.xlsx", which should return as "Birthing" but it returns as "".

Comment: `path = path.ToLower();` - `ToLower()` returns a new string, it does not (and cannot) change the existing string in path.

Comment: God. Thank you very much.

Comment: Or write your own Contains method that uses the `String.IndexOf` overload that takes a string comparison: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_IndexOf_System_String_System_StringComparison_

Comment: There is a more [memory efficent way to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring)

Comment: Completely irrelevant nitpick, but in `path.Contains("obs") || path.Contains("obst")` the test for `path.Contains("obst")` is redundant, because a string containing "obst" will obviously also always contain "obs" ;-)

Comment: Don't use `ToLower`.  It will create an unneeded temporary string.  See the answer @Flydog57 below that avoids this.

Answer (score 1):

Contains is case sensitive, and judging by the ToLower() you know this.
However, ToLower() does not manipulate the path variable. Instead you should re-assign it. You can do so by changing `path.ToLower()` to `path = path.ToLower()`

Comment: `ToUpperInvariant` is ment to do this: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.string.toupperinvariant?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @kara This would also still require you to re-assign the variable.

Answer (score 0):

The ToLower method returns the adjusted string:

```
path = path.ToLower();
```

Answer (score 0):

Write an extension method that looks something like this:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool ContainsNoCase(this string stringToLookIn, string stringToFind)
    {
        return stringToLookIn.IndexOf(stringToFind, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
    }
}
```

and use `ContainsNoCase` in place of `Contains`

Comment: And one advantage over calling `ToLower` as the other answers recommend is that it doesn't create an unnecessary temporary string..

Comment: Would the down-voter like to comment on his/her rationale.  This works, and it doesn't require creating new string (via `ToLower` or `ToUpper`) for each comparison.  It also makes for pretty clear code.  Interestingly, every answer to this question has a down-vote.